# LastPage not defined - can't get "page x of y" - even after multiple compiles

Tags: header-footer, counters, lastpage

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[loose]{units}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}


% these commands use the fancyhdr package to get "x of y" style
% page numbering.  The headrulewidth command gets rid of a decorative 
% horizontal rule that is default with "fancy" pagestyle.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\cfoot{{Cyclic triaxial test report  \ \ \ \ \ \ \   Page \thepage\ of \pageref{{LastPage}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Test ID: {testid} \\ {{\bf PRELIMINARY REPORT - NOT FOR ENGINEERING USE!}}}}

\subsection*{1}
\subsection*{2}
\subsection*{3}
\clearpage 
\subsection*{a}
\clearpage 
\subsection*{b}
\clearpage 
\subsection*{c}
\clearpage 
\subsection*{d}
\clearpage 
\clearpage 
\end{document}
```

Can anyone offer advice? As the title says, even after multiple compiles, I can't get `LastPage` to work. I'm using `pdfLaTeX`.

Comment: Your code is far from minimal.

Comment: Very sorry for offending you. I assumed my problem may have stemmed from a package conflict, so I left those in. The `subsection`s and `clearpage`s retain the page structure of my document, which is pertinent to the issue of footers and pagecounts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppress the extra pair of braces in the argument of `\pageref`; you have

```
\pageref{{LastPage}}
```

and it should be

```
\pageref{LastPage}
```

The extra pair of braces causes LaTeX to look for the wrong string `{LastPage}` to produce the cross-reference (the right string is `LastPage`). Your code produces some warnings about this:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `{LastPage}' on page 1 undefined on input line 35.
```

The code with some modifications explained before:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,oneside,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[loose]{units}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}


% these commands use the fancyhdr package to get "x of y" style
% page numbering.  The headrulewidth command gets rid of a decorative 
% horizontal rule that is default with "fancy" pagestyle.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\fancyfoot[C]{{Cyclic triaxial test report\qquad Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}\qquad  Test ID: {testid} \\ {\bfseries PRELIMINARY REPORT -- NOT FOR ENGINEERING USE!}}}

\subsection*{1}
\subsection*{2}
\subsection*{3}
\clearpage 
\subsection*{a}
\clearpage 
\subsection*{b}
\clearpage 
\subsection*{c}
\clearpage 
\subsection*{d}AAA
\clearpage 
\clearpage 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed `\cfoot{...}` to the most modern `\fancyfoot[C]{...}` interfaz. I also fixed the `headheight` length; your MWE produces a warning

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: `\headheight` is too small (`12.0pt`): Make it
at least `13.59999pt`.
```

so I used the `geometry` settings to increase the length as suggested by he message. Notice also thet `\bf` is an old TeX command that shouldn't be used in modern documents; you should use `\bfseries` instead,

Perhaps you should conside other method for getting your spacing in the footer; you can use `\qquad` (as I did in my example code) or `\hspace{<length>}` instead of all those single spaces together.

Comment: Nice! How could we imagine that solution!?

Comment: This is a bit of a tangent, but can you elaborate about the advantages of `\fancyfoot[C]{...}`? I haven't noticed a difference between it and `\cfoot{...}`.

Comment: @Tom the author of `fancyhdr` implemented `\fancyhead`, `\fancyfoot` since version 1.99 (1996) and declared "more or less deprecated" the initial family `\chead`, `\lhead`, etc (although they still can be used and the documentation itself uses them). `\fancyhead`, `\fancyfoot` have a more convenient syntax: for example, in `twoside` mode, using `\lhead[a]{b}` it's not immediately clear which ("a" or "b") will go on even and which on odd pages; on the other hand, `\fancyhead[LE]{...}`, `\fancyhead[LO]{...}` clearly shows what goes where. The implementation is also better.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Not speaking about the power of `[RO,LE]` :)

Comment: @tohecz sure; but the space in the comment was too short :)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently tested a version with `\pdfximage` and `\pdflastximagepages` via `lualatex` for this situation, but I am not recommending it for this particular problem in production. If a generated PDF file is empty or broken, this example stops the next run of TeX if that (empty) PDF file is not deleted in advance.

**Edit:** Next to it, not all books start at page 1 and `\pdfximage` command could be used later in the document, so this example is for demonstration only, it would need improvements.

```
%! lualatex example.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\def\myfile{example.pdf}
\IfFileExists{\myfile}  % Is document typeset for the first time?
  {\pdfximage{\myfile}} % Positive response...
  {\relax}              % Negative response...
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{Page \thepage\ of \the\pdflastximagepages}
\begin{document}
Some text.\par\newpage Some more text.
\end{document}
```

I am sorry I tend to solve the problem by avoiding the use of the `lastpage` package instead of answering the question. The reason is that we often need before the last page to refer to, e.g. when omitting the Colophon or an empty page or even many pages, e.g. when book contains Appendixes, pages for notes, pages with advertisements etc. This is my common solution where I can put `\label{mylastpage}` anywhere in the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{mylastpage}}
\begin{document}
Some text.\newpage Some more text.
\label{mylastpage}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE, part 1]
[image: MWE, part 2]

Comment: While this might be a valuable comment (I'm not sure, I haven't studied the question in details), I don't see how does this answer the question.

Comment: @tohecz Oh, thank you for letting me know, I see, I would need to implement it in the footer for instance. I'll improve it soon.